# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files (gdalbuildvrt)

Tags: gdal, virtual-raster

I tried to build a virtual raster from 2600 GeoTIFF's and got this message:

> OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: [...]

```
gdalbuildvrt -resolution average -r nearest -input_file_list /tmp/processing/buildvrtInputFiles.txt /home/map/Ar/virt.vrt
```

I tryed with 1000 files and got the same error. Using 250 files is working fine!
The files are in average 1.5MB. I got 16GB of RAM and running GDAL 2.2.3 on Linux Mint.

Comment: Increase ulimit files

Comment: I did, but maybe I did something wrong or this is just not working. I followed that instructions: https://posidev.com/blog/2009/06/04/set-ulimit-parameters-on-ubuntu/